# what is full path coverage testing in java?

Tags: java, testing, path

```
    public int f(int i) {
    int j = i+1;
      if(i % 2 == 0) {
        j = doit(i);
      }
      if (i % 3 == 0) {
        j = doit(i+1);
      }
    return j;
    }
```

How many different values of the argument i are necessary to achieve full path coverage testing of this
method?

Write down that many different values, which will achieve full path coverage testing of that method?

what exactly is full path coverage testing? how do you do it? 
(please explain in detail, i have a test coming up and i'm still really confused by this)
TIA

Comment: Well to his credit he does mention a test ;-). As a hint in this case you need 4 inputs, you want a combination where each expression is true and false as FF TF FT TT so each combination of code paths is tested.

Comment: its from a practice test, the answers where compiled by student so idk if they are 100% accurate, but i'm confused about what exactly full path coverage testing is

Answer (score 2):

**If you test your code in such a way that all possible paths of the logic are tested, it's termed as full path testing.**

In your example you have two alternate paths which result into 4 combinations below:

1. Control goes in first if block only (e.g. **i = 2**)
2. Control goes in second if block only (e.g. **i = 3**)
3. Control goes in both if blocks (e.g. **i = 6**)
4. Control doesn't go in both the if blocks (e.g. **i = 5**)

If you test your code with above 4 scenarios covered, it would be full path testing of your code.

Comment: aha i think im starting to get it now, basically i has to be tt,tf,ft,ff for they methods we are trying to test. so will the different values of the argument i are necessary to achieve full path coverage testing of this method would always be 2^n where n is the amount of methods we are trying to go through?

Comment: @cloud9resident The over all idea is to test each possible flow of the logic. If you would have `if-else` block then only 2 test scenarios would have been sufficient, one for `if` and one for `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Full path coverage is when every possible route through your code is executed during the testing (in different iterations.  It doesn't all have to be during one test).  In the case of the code above, it would require four different values of `i` to trigger:

- First if, not second
- Second if, not first
- Both ifs
- Neither if

Since this seems to be homework, I'll leave discovering what values of `i` are needed up to you.

Comment: the answer is 0,1,2,5 but i don't know how they got that answer, do you just plug in those numbers for i and see if you can go through each path through they method??